# Python: How does one quickly grep at the interpreter prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to locate the mro method. So I did:

```
class Foo():
   pass

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

x = Bar()
```

Then I started to poke around inside it by using **dir** eventually I wound up doing `dir(builtins)` which lists things alphabetically which is nice... but is there a better way to **grep** for stuff? Some way to do:

> dir(builtins)|grep 'mro'

and quickly locate the method

Answer (score 0):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you can filter sequence (iterable):

```
[x for x in dir(builtins) if 'mro' in x]
```

Comment: ... put that in a function?